# How to white-list inline script in the content security policy (CSP) of a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm using the library [list.js](https://github.com/javve/list.js) in a Chrome extension, and it uses inline-scripting to insert the pagination in the web pages, which included as `<a>` element like this:

```
<a href="javascript:function Z(){Z=\"\"}Z()"></a>
```

So, in order to make this work in the extension I guess I need to white-list it to the content security policy (CSP).

To do so, I tried to relax the CSP for the inline script, as described in the [Chrome docs here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing), but I can't do it and still getting the console error:

> Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'sha256-{HASH}'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline
>   execution.

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage) to generate a sha256 hash and tried:

```
$echo -n "function Z(){Z=\"\"}Z()" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

$echo -n "function Z(){Z=""}Z()" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

After I get the hash, I include it in the `manifest.json` as follows:

```
...
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-{HASH}'; object-src 'self'",
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to fork the library and fix its use of inline js?

Comment: Maybe add your own functionality to run immediately after what this script does, and then manipulate those links - convert `javascript:function Z(){Z=\"\"}Z()` to a proper event handler, and then remove/null/`#` the href attribute afterwards ...?